# try-catch statement in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

According to the [JSX reference](https://jsx.github.io/doc/statementref.html), this is what a try-catch statement must look like

```
try {
  statement*
} [catch (varname : type) {
  statement*
}]* [finally {
  statement*
}]
```

I tried the following

```
try {
  console.log(window.device.version)
} catch (e : TypeError) {
  console.log('Error')
}
```

Which results in the error

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ) (11:15)
>
> ```
> 9  |     try {
> 10 |       console.log(window.device.version)
> 11 |     } catch (e : TypeError) {
>    |                ^
> 12 |       console.log('Error')
> 13 |     }
> 14 |     return (
> ```

What is the correct way to use a try-catch statement in JSX then ?

Comment: The actual spec is at http://facebook.github.io/jsx/; the thing you've found is something different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### React JSX

It looks like a TypeScript style. Just use `try{ } catch(e) { console.error(e); }` would be fine.

Take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), and don't forget that JSX is just a syntax sugar for `React.createElement`.

### JSX - a faster, safer, easier JavaScript

The link you mentioned is **not** react React JSX, but a whole new thing call DeNA JSX.

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/jsx/JSX/issues/255) in DeNA JSX, and [this PR](https://github.com/jsx/JSX/pull/351).

Comment: I don't know JSX (not my domain), but does it mean that we should have different tags for DeNA JSX and Facebook JSX?

Answer (score 6):

In JSX or JavaScript you can write it like this

```
try {
console.log(window.device.version) 
} catch (e) {
console.log('Error')
}
```

If you are using TypeScript your previous code should work

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

The try statement lets you test a block of code for errors.

The catch statement lets you handle the error.

The throw statement lets you create custom errors.

The final statement lets you execute code, after try and catch, regardless of the result.

---

The basic concept goes like this:

```
  try {
   // Block of code to try
}
catch(err) {
    // Block of code to handle errors
}
```

So, let's now make a scenario where an error would occur:

```js
// It will try to run the task, but it will fail

try {
  eval(console.log("Hello world));  // Just add the missing quote at the end of 'world' word and it will pass :) 
}

// So, here is where we catch the error and display it to the user

catch(error) { 
  console.error(error);
  
  // expected output:
  // "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"
  // Note - error messages will vary depending on browser
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling has the following syntax..

```
try {

  // code...

} catch (err) {

  // error handling

}
```

See this: https://javascript.info/try-catch

But try-catch will not catch all the errors in React.js code. Try-catch will detect errors in an imperative code whereas React is declarative in nature

Use error boundaries as defined in React 16 and above..

1. Create a component using componentDidCatch
2. Surround your component to be tested using the error boundary.

See this-(official react docs):https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Answer (score -3):

```
try{
// code for error testing
   }
catch (e) {
// code for error handeling
            console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer